# Clear the terminal in rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, unix

In terminal, you can clear the terminal by typing $ `clear` (gives a large block of clear lines) or control+l (although this only moves the last line to to top).   How do you accomplish this once you have started the server using $ `rails s`, or am I stuck with just holding return/enter for a while?

Comment: Did you try `control+l`? That works for me.

Comment: Just curious why you want to clear the terminal???

Comment: I am getting errors trying to learn rails, and want to separate the different page requests easily

Comment: @Frost `control+l` only works if I shut the server down,   not while it is running

Comment: @chris Frisina:- you can `Enter` as many time as you want to separate the different page requests..........though it is not answer to your question it may help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In gnome terminal: `Terminal -> Reset and Clear`.

[image]

I mapped it to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for OSX

Comment: I never looked in the darm menu bar! Duh!   Ctrl+K and ⌘+K work to "Clear All"  under edit...

Comment: darn looks like dam !  d a r n <=> d a m

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu,

```
system 'clear'
```

In Windows

```
system 'cls'
```

**Note:** If you are using terminal inside some IDE like `MyEclipse` then you can remove terminal data by pressing "Clear Console" that is at right side of console even while server is running. Like that different IDE's have different ways of clearing console data. For standalone console like the `ubuntu terminal` or `Windows terminal` while server on run, you can't remove data.

Comment: getting problems with windows or ubuntu?

Comment: linux,   it's just like im typing in the server, and when i hit enter it goes to next line.    The server is running, so there is no command line to accept the command,  that is why I am wondering if it is possible...